# Stack Level Too Deep Error In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error in Rails and there's no other information to help me figure out why.

```
SystemStackError in UserController#students
stack level too deep
```

My user controller is as follows

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :students, :mentors]
  ...
  def students
    @users = Student.where(:verify_code => 'VERIFIED')
  end
end
```

Even when I remove the @users line the error persists.

EDIT: The error seems to happen to every single route aside from the `devise_for :users` and to_root, which means just the User controller.

User Model

```
require 'json'
require 'socket'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :roles
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :ign, :server, :roles, :presence => true
  validate :summoner_exists
  validate :valid_roles
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :ign, :server, :tier, :roles, :type


  def valid_roles
    valid_role_array = ['Top', 'Mid', 'Jungle', 'AD Carry', 'Support']
    self.roles.each do |role| 
      unless valid_role_array.include?(role)
        self.roles.delete(role)
      end
    end
  end

  def summoner_verified?
    return self.verify_code == 'VERIFIED'
  end

  def summoner_verify
    rune_pages = shurima_api(self.server, 'rune_pages', self.acctid)
    unless rune_pages
      return false
    else
      rune_pages.each do |page|
        if (page['name'] == self.verify_code)
          self.verify_code = 'VERIFIED'
          self.save
          return true
        end
      end
    end
    return false
  end

  def summoner_exists
    json = shurima_api(self.server, 'summoner', self.ign)
    unless json
      errors.add(:ign, "The summoner name \"#{self.ign}\" doesn't exist on #{self.server}")
    else
      self.summonerid = json['summonerId']
      self.acctid = json['acctId']
      self.verify_code = Array.new(10){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
      eligible_to_mentor
    end
  end

  def eligible_to_mentor
    leagues = shurima_api(self.server, 'leagues', self.summonerid)
    unless leagues
      errors.add(:ign, "That summoner doesn't seem to meet the requirements to become a mentor. Make sure you're at least in a Platinum League")
      return false
    end
    leagues.each do |league| 
      if (league['queue'] == 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5')
        self.tier = league['tier']
      end
    end
    eligible_tiers = ['PLATINUM', 'DIAMOND', 'CHALLENGER']
    if (self.type == 'Mentor' && !eligible_tiers.include?(self.tier))
      errors.add(:mentor, "Mentors must be at least PLATINUM.")
    end
  end

  def shurima_api(server, method, args)
    host, port = 'ip removed', 714
    TCPSocket.open(host, port) do |socket|
      ready = IO.select([socket], [socket], nil, 8)
      return false unless ready
      socket.puts server + "&" + method + "&" + args.to_s
      message = socket.gets.chomp
      if message == '"Unknown error"'
        return false
      end
      return JSON.parse(message)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you performing any application logic in the view or the helpers that could be causing the error?

Comment: Do you have any scopes in your `User` model? Something may be causing a recursive loop. Post the model code and try running the query as a task with `--trace` to see the method chain.

Comment: @Matt No scopes. I posted the model. How do I run it with --trace?

Comment: @MattGarriott No, I'm not. It's just a table showing users.

Comment: Are you sure the error doesn't tell you the line number it fails on?

Comment: @Pavling `actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70` is the only line that shows up.

Comment: Stick the whole error up on a gist, so we can look - I've never seen Rails generate a 1-line error ;-)

Comment: @Pavling, the error still happens on production but at a different place now. [Here's the gist in development.](https://gist.github.com/Anujan/5608598#file-gistfile1-txt)

Comment: If the error is happening throughout the application, can you post ApplicationController, ApplicationHelper... anything that would be affecting multiple controllers?

Comment: @chrislopresto Both of those are unchanged.

Comment: @uDaY Here's the [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/Anujan/072ce2296d3c22845b6a)

Comment: mybad gemlock file please so that we can know the version of gems you are using.

Comment: Please post you full users controller. Somewhere in your code you have something looping infinitely.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie [User Controller and Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2498f4911d9112285f65)

Comment: Thanks @Anujan I didn't see anything there so how about the application controller.

Comment: Maybe post your `layout/application.html.erb` file if you have some logic here?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie [Application Controller](https://gist.github.com/Anujan/65a671dfba4ca84ee747) It's the default.

Comment: @jokklan [Here's the layout](https://gist.github.com/Anujan/80b2458140518220b20f) The helper functions are the ones that are found [here](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/app/helpers/navbar_helper.rb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by renaming the `request` method to `request_mentor` because it was causing the infinite loop.

Comment: What request method, you never posted one?

Comment: @Matt, it was in the [User Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630082/stack-level-too-deep-error-in-rails/16680382?noredirect=1#comment23992063_16630082)

Comment: ... which you [never](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16630082/revisions) had posted.

Comment: I linked the comment in which I posted it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630082/stack-level-too-deep-error-in-rails/16680382?noredirect=1#comment23992063_16630082

Comment: http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/ `request` is a reserved word...